# Does the Daylight spell count as "direct sunlight" for the purposes of Sunlight Sensitivity?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Here is the feature in question:

> **Sunlight Sensitivity.** You have disadvantage on attack rolls and on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight when you, the target of
> your attack, or whatever you are trying to perceive is in **direct
> sunlight.**

And the spell, **Daylight**:

> A 60-foot-radius sphere of light spreads out from a point you choose within range. The sphere is bright light and sheds dim light for an additional 60 feet.
>
> If you chose a point on an object you are holding or one that isn't being worn or carried, the light shines from the object and moves with it. Completely covering the affected object with an opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the light.
>
> If any of this spell's area overlaps with an area of darkness created by a spell of 3rd level or lower, the spell that created the darkness is dispelled.

Clearly it is not explicitly spelled out in the text, but still I'm not sure if the reader is meant to assume an intended effect, since "Daylight" and "Sunlight" are synonymous.

Comment: I concede. The linked response answers my question.

Comment: Cool! We can link them then. Thank you for posting a new way to find that information. :)